# Autogenerate GUID at SaveChanges()

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

Is there any solution or update to make EntityFramework detects `uniqueidentifier` columns with default value `newid()`, when generating the enitiy model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. EF doesn't support (yet?) to define custom conventions. (One of the first CTPs for `DbContext` contained a first proposal for custom conventions but they have been removed in the final release due to the complexity of this feature. I don't know if or when they will return in a later release.) You have to live with the standard conventions available and they say that a property of type `Guid` isn't database generated by default. You must mark `Guid` properties explicitly with data annotations or Fluent API to override this default.